# How to fix gibberish when this char: " ‘ " is written on an HTML file

Tags: html, character-encoding

I work with content writers which include the char " `‘` " in their texts (they send me .doc files).

Is there a way to make browsers recognize this char?

Untill now I always went through the text and replaced it with a regular " `'` " and I find it very annoying.

I tried including the meta for UTF8 and it's not effective.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `‘` the with `&#8216;`, which is the HTML code for it.

Comment: I don't want to be replacing chars in my html... I'm looking for something that will work for me in a global way without any effort. Worst case scenario I will  write a .js script that replaces it :P

Comment: I don't see why you prefer writing a script over a "Replace all" in any text editor.

Comment: 1. it's texts that I update everyday almost. 
2. I find it faster writing a script one and including it in the template I work on everyday - hail laziness B-)